# Client does not have permission to access the desired Firebase data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire, firebase-security

I have a page that is calling `addCheckin()` method which is inside a controller. In the controller, I am trying to create a reference as follows:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/" + $scope.whichuser + "/meetings/" +$scope.whichmeeting + "/checkins");
```

`$scope.whichuser` and `$scope.whichmeeting` are the `$routeParams` that I am passing from another route.
Here's my checkin controller-

```
myApp.controller("CheckinsController",
    ['$scope','$rootScope','$firebaseArray','$routeParams','$firebaseObject',
    function($scope,$rootScope,$firebaseArray,$routeParams,$firebaseObject){

        $scope.whichuser = $routeParams.uid;
        $scope.whichmeeting = $routeParams.mid;

        var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/" + $scope.whichuser + "/meetings/" +$scope.whichmeeting + "/checkins");

        $scope.addCheckin = function(){
            var checkinInfo = $firebaseArray(ref);
            var data={
                firstname:$scope.firstname,
                lastname:$scope.lastname,
                email:$scope.email,
                date:firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            }

            checkinInfo.$add(data);
        }

}]);/*controller*/
```

There are two errors that I am getting here-

Error 1:

> Error: permission_denied at /users/Vp2P1MqKm7ckXqV2Uy3OzTnn6bB3/meetings: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

Error 2:

> Error: permission_denied at /users/Vp2P1MqKm7ckXqV2Uy3OzTnn6bB3/meetings/-KT5tqMYKXsFssmcRLm6/checkins: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

And this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Here's my JSON tree of the database:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "43ZU72ndoKb9LSEjBODKXe3nrou1" : {
      "email" : "roy@123.com",
      "firstname" : "Roy",
      "lastname" : "Marshal",
      "regUser" : "43ZU72ndoKb9LSEjBODKXe3nrou1"
    },
    "BHcYb40FC8YlCKL54ngyMhxPx2q1" : {
      "date" : 1475574109981,
      "email" : "sky@on.com",
      "firstname" : "Sky",
      "lastname" : "Thakur",
      "meetings" : {
        "-KTE3_45wXBqd-_yR1xv" : {
          "date" : 1475574125198,
          "name" : "ARET"
        }
      },
      "regUser" : "BHcYb40FC8YlCKL54ngyMhxPx2q1"
    },
    "Vp2P1MqKm7ckXqV2Uy3OzTnn6bB3" : {
      "email" : "jon@me.com",
      "firstname" : "John",
      "lastname" : "Cena",
      "meetings" : {
        "-KT5tqMYKXsFssmcRLm6" : {
          "date" : 1475437094667,
          "name" : "hourly"
        },
        "-KTAvH-ZkWyxrJrK_SDb" : {
          "date" : 1475521356544,
          "name" : "Hourly"
        },
        "-KTAwV69txdeT4i_horE" : {
          "date" : 1475521676006,
          "name" : "asdfg"
        },
        "-KTAwkH35EyPQZ17DmN9" : {
          "date" : 1475521742244,
          "name" : "qwerty"
        },
        "-KTAwsrqe24e8wFfRxpN" : {
          "date" : 1475521777422,
          "name" : "asfdsf"
        },
        "-KTAyYPSZLQUtOJ4g8Ak" : {
          "date" : 1475522213781,
          "name" : "Yearly"
        },
        "-KTB05PfXZLLk9Of3_Nb" : {
          "date" : 1475522881473,
          "name" : "Meet"
        },
        "-KTBG2cP9YLoP4lalN5M" : {
          "date" : 1475527064378,
          "name" : "JOI"
        }
      },
      "regUser" : "Vp2P1MqKm7ckXqV2Uy3OzTnn6bB3"
    }
  }
}
```

My database rules are:

```
{ 
  "rules": { 
    ".read": true, 
    ".write": true 
  } 
}
```

I also posted this question before, but didn't get any appropriate solution.

Comment: Those are not valid rues: `read:"true",
write:"true"`. In fact, you won't be able to save them. Please include the exact text from your Firebase Console (copy/paste is your friend here).

Comment: `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}`  @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I've never seen a permission denied error with those rules. Can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: jsbin is not possible as its a huge project. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Can you re-create the problem in a tiny project and put that on jsbin? See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry Frank, its really not possible for me to create a bin for this problem. Whatever the scenario is I have mentioned in the post. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I test rules like the ones you have regularly, they never reject writes for me. I hope someone else sees what's going wrong, because I can't help further without a repo.

Comment: Anyways, thanks for the help @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: With these rules it's pretty much impossible to get these errors... Maybe you have the config wrong? like you're trying to work on your dev DB but actually are connected to prod DB?